# Navigation Controller "back button" text: Presented Modally

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, modalviewcontroller

I'm creating an array of view controllers, adding them to a UINavigation Controller, and then presenting them modally.

I cannot however set the text to the "back" button in each view to anything other than the word "back".

This is the code:

```
//The View Controllers and Array
VC1 *vc1 = [[VC1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC1" bundle:nil];
VC2 *vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC2" bundle:nil];
VC3 *vc3 = [[VC3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC3" bundle:nil];
NSArray * viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc3, vc2, vc1, nil];

// Create the nav controller and set the view controllers.
UINavigationController*  theNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
initWithRootViewController:vc3];
[theNavController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];

// Display the nav controller modally.
[self presentModalViewController:theNavController animated:YES];
```

I have tried the following in the init of each VC:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
barButton.title = @"Acknowledge Briefings Read";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

... but it does not work. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Also, related, I'd ideally like to navigate the stack in a "forwards" direction. Is this possible using a navigation controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything view-wise in the init. You need to wait for viewDidLoad (or willAppear or didAppear), since nothing has been drawn in init (in the case of the nav controller, the previous item will be affected).

Here is what I do (in viewDidLoad):

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButon = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButon];
```

Comment: Hi Adam, Thank you. Do you know how I'd use this approach to get to the next view controller in the navigation controller stack though?

Answer (score 1):

Hey it might work for you:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"Acknowledge Briefings Read";
```

This code should go in the viewController which is currently visible. You should add it in the viewWillApear

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The back button test is automatically set to the title attribute of the UIViewController that is on the top of the stack. So in the viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad of each view controller set self.title to the text you want to appear in the "Back" button when a new view is pushed onto the stack.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to make the nab button appear on the right of the screen though? I want to appear to the user to move forwards through the stack of VC's ... at the moment the nab button appears on the left of the screen

Comment: @LeeBarringer You should really read the View Controller Programming Guide for insight into designing your application.

Comment: Its not a great deal of use for very specific problems like this. Experience is the way forward, or lacking this, as I do, drawing on the insight of the very kind people on this site.